# Taking screenshot doesn't work when using @State in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to take a screenshot of the selected area using CGRect. It works fine if I don't use @State variable. But I need to use @State variable too.
Here is my code...

```
struct ScreenShotTest: View {

    @State var abc = 0 //Works well if I remove the line

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            let image = self.takeScreenshot(theRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
            print(image)
        }) {
            Text("Take Screenshot")
                .padding(.all, 10)
                .background(Color.blue)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
    }
}


extension UIView {
    var renderedImage: UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
}

extension View {
        func takeScreenshot(theRect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: theRect)
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return hosting.view.renderedImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, but with an EnvironmentObject. I solved it by declaring the EnvironmentObject in an outer view and passing it as a plain variable to the inner view that was crashing when I used it. This is pared way down from my real code, but it should convey the idea.

```
struct Sample: View {
    @State private var isSharePresented: Bool = false
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    static var screenshot: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            // Hack to get a black background.
            ZStack {
                Spacer()
                    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.black)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                VStack {
                    CompletionContent(model: Model.theModel)
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {
                        model.advanceToNext()
                    }) {
                        Text("Continue", comment: "Dismiss this view")
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(.init(UIColor.link))
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Button(action: {
                            Sample.screenshot = self.takeScreenshot(theRect: (geometry.frame(in: .global)))
                            self.isSharePresented = true
                        }) {
                            VStack {
                                Image("blank")
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                    .resizable()
                                    .frame(width: 20, height: 30)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isSharePresented, onDismiss: {
            print("Dismiss")
        }, content: {
            ActivityViewController(screenshot: Sample.screenshot!)
        })
    }
}

struct SampleContent : View {
    var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Content that uses the model variable goes here")
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var renderedImage: UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let context: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        self.layer.render(in: context)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return capturedImage
    }
}

extension View {
    func takeScreenshot(theRect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: theRect)
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return hosting.view.renderedImage
    }
}

struct ActivityViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var screenshot: UIImage
    var applicationActivities: [UIActivity]? = nil
    
    func makeUIViewController(
        context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>)
    -> UIActivityViewController {
        let controller = UIActivityViewController(
            activityItems: [screenshot], applicationActivities: applicationActivities)
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIActivityViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ActivityViewController>) {
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get it: what's the relationship between SampleContent and Sample views?